# Creation of lua object from c++ base class

Tags: c++, oop, lua, luabind

I have exported from C++ into lua such base class:

> ```
> class IState
> {
>     public:
>         virtual ~IState() { }
>
>         virtual void Init() = 0;
>         virtual void Update(float dSeconds) = 0;
>         virtual void Shutdown() = 0;
>         virtual string Type() const = 0;
> };
>
> // Wraper of state base class for lua
> struct IStateWrapper : IState, luabind::wrap_base
> {
>     virtual void Init() { call<void>("Init"); }
>     virtual void Update(float dSeconds) { call<void>("Update", dSeconds); }
>     virtual void Shutdown() { call<void>("Shutdown"); }
>     virtual string Type() const { return call<string>("Type"); }
> };
> ```

Export code:

> ```
>         class_<IState, IStateWrapper>("IState")
>             .def("Init", &IState::Init)
>             .def("Update", &IState::Update)
>             .def("Shutdown", &IState::Shutdown)
> ```

The next part: I have StateManager with function: `void StateManager::Push(IState*)` and it's export:

```
        class_<StateManager>("StateManager")
            .def("Push", &StateManager::Push)
```

Now, I want to create object of type IState in Lua and push it into StateManager:

```
-- Create a table for storing object of IState cpp class
MainState = {}

-- Implementatio of IState::Init pure virtual function
function MainState:Init()
    print 'This is Init function'
end

function MainState:Update()
    print 'this is update'
end

function MainState:Shutdown()
    print 'This is shutdown'
end

state = StateManager
state.Push(MainState)
```

Of course, this won't work. I don't know how to say that MainState if the object of type IState:

```
error: No matching overload found, candidates: void Push(StateManager&,IState*)
```

---

**UPD**

```
    module(state, "Scene") [
        class_<StateManager>("StateManager")
            .def("Push", &StateManager::Push),

        class_<IState, IStateWrapper>("IState")
            .def("Init", &IState::Init)
            .def("Update", &IState::Update)
            .def("Shutdown", &IState::Shutdown)
    ];

    globals(state)["StateManager"] = Root::Get().GetState(); // GetState() returns pointer to obj
```

After example:

```
class 'MainState' (Scene.IState)
function MainState:__init()
    Scene.IState.__init(self, 'MainState')
end
...
state = StateManager
state:Push(MainState())
```

error: no static '__init' in class 'IState'

And should `state = StateManager` has brackets? With them there is error that no such operator.

Comment: "And should state = StateManager has brackets?" I don't know; what do you want it to do? Do you want to *create* a `StateManager` object, or do you want to use an already existing one? I can't read your mind; you need to be more clear on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @NicolBolas `globals(state)["StateManager"] = Root::Get().GetState();` Here I set `StateManager` to some pointer, that's why, I think, I wrote it without brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just throw a table at Luabind. If you intend to derive from a Luabind-defined class, you have to follow the rules of Luabind. You have to [create a Lua class with Luabind's tools](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#defining-classes-in-lua), derived from your `IState` class. That would look like this:

```
class 'MainState' (IState) --Assuming that you registered IState in the global table and not a Luabind module.

function MainState:__init()
    IState.__init(self, 'MainState')
end

function MainState:Init()
    print 'This is Init function'
end

function MainState:Update()
    print 'this is update'
end

function MainState:Shutdown()
    print 'This is shutdown'
end

state = StateManager()
state:Push(MainState())
```

Also, take note of the changes to the last two lines. Specifically, how StateManager is *called*, not simply set into `state`). Also, how you use `state:` and not `state.`. I have no idea how this code even functioned in your example.